# getting an xml attribute from other attribute in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, xml

I have an xml where I have xml tag in an xml file like below

```
<Relationship Id="rId6" Type="abc" Target="xyz" TargetMode="External"/>
```

Now I have only Target attribute text i.e. 'xyz'. Now I have to find Id attribute using this Target text in react. I have tried using query-selector, but that didn't worked. Can anyone suggest me any solution.

Comment: In React, you should (try) not use regular JS solutions, you should use React's solutions, that's why you're using React and not plain JS. I am unsure of the context of your problem, please list more information about where this component resides in your app and a deeper explanation of what was previously done. Also a quick explanation of what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to update text based on the hyperlink in a word document. So I have created zip of word document and extracted that zip to get xml files. One xml contains actual text and other contains link to the text. I am trying to get Id of the tag containing target attribute and get text from the other xml using the same Id. In this case I am trying to get Id if target='xyz'